# Access POST values in Symfony2 request object

Tags: php, symfony, http-post

OK, this is a newbie question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.  In a controller in Symfony2, I want to access the POST value from one of my forms.  In the controller I have:

```php
public function indexAction()
{ 
    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new ContactType());
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $name_value = $request->request->get('name');
```

Unfortunately `$name_value` isn't returning anything.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

## Symfony 2.2

this solution is deprecated since 2.3 and will be removed in 3.0, [see documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html#passing-a-request-to-form-submit-deprecated)

```
$form->getData();
```

gives you an array for the form parameters

from [symfony2 book](http://symfony.com/pdf/Symfony_book_2.0.pdf?v=2) page 162 (Chapter 12: Forms)

[...] sometimes, you may just want to use a form without a class, and get back an array of the submitted
data. This is actually really easy:

```
public function contactAction(Request $request) {
  $defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
  $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
  ->add('name', 'text')
  ->add('email', 'email')
  ->add('message', 'textarea')
  ->getForm();
  if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bindRequest($request);
    // data is an array with "name", "email", and "message" keys
    $data = $form->getData();
  }
  // ... render the form
}
```

You can also access POST values (in this case "name") directly through the request object, like so:

```
$this->get('request')->request->get('name');
```

**Be advised, however, that in most cases using the getData() method is a better choice, since it
returns the data (usually an object) after it's been transformed by the form framework.**

When you want to access the form token, you have to use the answer of Problematic
`$postData = $request->request->get('contact');` because the `getData()` removes the element from the array

---

## Symfony **2.3**

since 2.3 you should use `handleRequest` instead of `bindRequest`:

```
 $form->handleRequest($request);
```

[see documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions)

Comment: This is great, and now is the best answer.  $form->getData() didn't exist or wasn't documented when I asked the question.

Comment: to bind request data to form in newest versions you should use $form->handleRequest($request); instead of $form->submit($request); i think. More details http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Answer (score 127):

The form post values are stored under the name of the form in the request. For example, if you've overridden the `getName()` method of ContactType() to return "contact", you would do this:

```
$postData = $request->request->get('contact');
$name_value = $postData['name'];
```

If you're still having trouble, try doing a `var_dump()` on `$request->request->all()` to see all the post values.

Comment: Thank you.  The var_dump helped, I ended up attacking this with a full name to recover the form data   e.g. $postData = $request->request->get('acme_somebundle_contact_type')

Comment: See the answer from timaschew below, since this was asked, Symfony2 added a new method: $form->getData();

Comment: If you've overridden the `getName()`, then it makes sense to not hardcode names: `$request->request->get($form->getName());`

Answer (score 38):

what worked for me was using this:

```
$data = $request->request->all();
$name = $data['form']['name'];
```

Comment: This is what Problematic mentioned, + see comment of @meze there

Answer (score 17):

There is one trick with `ParameterBag::get()` method. You can set [`$deep` parameter](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php#L101) to `true` and access the required deep nested value without extra variable:

```
$request->request->get('form[some][deep][data]', null, true);
```

Also you have possibility to set a default value (2nd parameter of `get()` method), it can avoid redundant `isset($form['some']['deep']['data'])` call.

Comment: The third parameter has been deprecated and removed from 3.0 _Note: Finding deep items is deprecated since version 2.8, to be removed in 3.0._: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/351b234f0791727054e95040d3c28cf3d772c9a9/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.php#L77

Answer (score 8):

The field data can be accessed in a controller with:
Listing 12-34

```
$form->get('dueDate')->getData();
```

In addition, the data of an unmapped field can also be modified directly:
Listing 12-35

```
$form->get('dueDate')->setData(new \DateTime());
```

page 164 symfony2 book(generated on October 9, 2013)

Answer (score 7):

I access the ticketNumber parameter for my multipart post request in the following way.

```
$data = $request->request->all();
$ticketNumber = $data["ticketNumber"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that in order to get the request data, bound and validated by the form object, you must use :

`$form->getClientData();`

Comment: getClientData is deprecated. Use getData, getViewData, getNormData .... The Form component is really messy in SF2 (they really should get inspired by Java world and the cool RequestDataBinder ....)

Answer (score 0):

Symfony [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html) to get request data

> Finally, the raw data sent with the request body can be accessed using getContent():

$content = $request->getContent();

Answer (score -14):

If you are newbie, welcome to Symfony2, an open-source project so if you want to learn a lot, you can open the source !

From "Form.php" :

getData()
getNormData()
getViewData()

You can find more details in this file.

Comment: Always use the Symfony way, $_POST, $request is dirty

Comment: Yeah I am not good for explanation ^^ but this is exactly the same solution than the one confirmed ``$form->getData();`` I know people are lazy and want a solution without thinking a bit ;-(