# get->Request in Symfony2

Tags: php, post, symfony

I have a very simple question, How can I get the POST values from get->Request();

```
public function emptytrashAction(){
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $portfolio_id = $_POST["test"];
}
```

I dont want to use the `$_POST` variable and the form I submit just contain this hidden field test. The form is,

```
 <form name="empt_trash" action="{{ path('MunichInnovationGroupPatentBundle_portfolio_emptytrash') }}" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value={{ selected_portfolio.id }}>
    <input class="button3 tooltip" name = "submit" type="submit" value="Empty"></a>
 </form>
```

How can I get the value of the hidden field without using `$_POST`?

**Edit**

If a method use both GET and POST requests, For the Post request I check in my code like this

```
            if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
```

but it is not the symfony2 way then what is the proper way to check for the POST request?

Comment: haan kia hai but mujay nai mila koi solid jawab aap he bata dain :)

Comment: Could you please speak english?

Comment: @AlphaMale You can answer here ... j0k he wants me to add him on skype to solve my problem

Comment: Answer me If you know it

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916324/access-post-values-in-symfony2-request-object

Comment: No Worries.. Glad problem is solved.

Comment: AlphaMale can i ask u 1 question ?

Comment: getPostParameter() is used to get post values.

Comment: how can I verify if the request is get or post ?

Comment: Your method is also correct but once i used $request->isMethod('post');

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As simple as :

```
$request  = $this->getRequest();
$postData = $request->request->get('test');
```

**Note**: This solution is only valid for Symfony <2.4 version. For 2.4 [is deprecated](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/2e07338c5c58184318812f3852766a961b973df9) and removed for 3.0.

The new code for obtain the request should be:

```
$request = $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
$postData = $request->request->get('test');
```

Comment: Thanks j0k . Can I ask u one more simple question ?

Comment: Update your question or post a new one :)

Comment: but one my senior is saying me again and again its not the symfony2 way :(

Comment: His Comments : Annotate method with @Method and set value to post or get. Do not check in...

Comment: Well, [it's in the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions).

Answer (score 3):

$this->getRequest() is a deprecated method since symfony 2.4 and it will be removed in the version 3.0, so the best way to get the current request is through the following code:

```
//src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php
...

/*
 * ...
 * @deprecated Deprecated since version 2.4, to be removed in 3.0. Ask
 *             Symfony to inject the Request object into your controller
 *             method instead by type hinting it in the method's signature.
 */
public function getRequest()
{
    return $this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
}
```

Introduced by the following evolution,

[[FrameworkBundle] use the new request_stack service to get the Request object in the base Controller class.](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/2e07338c5c58184318812f3852766a961b973df9)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `getRequest()` method its deprecated its always a good idea to inject request into your controller. Define you action like this:

```
public function emptytrashAction(Request $request){
    $portfolio_id = $request->request->get('test');
}
```

Never use GLOBALS like POST or GET in your actions they are not secure.

Here you can find more details: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

Comment: if someone let me know the reasons of down vote it would be great. May be it will help me to make my answer more helpful and accurate.

Comment: Indeed, this is the proper solution!

Comment: In fact, the deprceation message seen in PhpUnit is clear and states exactly what Ashish said: `The Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::getRequest method is deprecated since Symfony 2.4 and will be removed in 3.0. The only reliable way to get the "Request" object is to inject it in the action method.` - So see that **the only reliable way is to inject** the Request itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$this->getRequest()->request->get($path)`

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Symfony2 Blog, you should use the Request object directly as a parameter of your methods in your controllers.

For a service, you can inject the object through the __construct method and store it in an internal property.

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack

To determine if your request method was post

```
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {...}
```