# Access HTML form data in Symfony2

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

I am new to Symfony. I have seen a lot of threads regarding this topic, but none have been able to answer the question that I have.

I have a "Contact" form on my site. This contact form submits to path('submit_query'), which calls the submitQueryController. I am not building the form through Symfony and I am not using an object or entity. My problem is that no matter what I do, I am unable to access the form data within the controller. I have tried every thread suggestion that I have seen, and I either get the REQUEST object with a whole bunch of data (none of which is my form data) or I get nothing.

Is there no easy way of accessing the posted form data from within the controller?

My HTML Form:

```
<form id="contact_form" role="form" action="{{ path('submit_query') }}" method="post">`
<div class="panel-body">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter your full name" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" class="col-sm-3 form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter a valid email address" data-validation="email length" data-validation-length="min1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="number" class="control-label">Contact Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Contact Telephone Number">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject" class="control-label">Subject</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="The subject of your query" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter a subject for your query" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="query" class="control-label">Query</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="query" rows="5" placeholder="Please enter a detailed description of your query" data-validation-error-msg="Please enter your query description" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min1"></textarea>
        </div>      
    </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer clearfix text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Query</button></div>
</form>
```

Controller:

When I try:

```
public function submitQueryAction(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->request->all();
    die(var_dump($data));
}
```

I get an empty array in "$data".

When I try:

```
public function submitQueryAction()
{
    $data = $this->getRequest()->request->all();
    die(var_dump($data));
}
```

I get a vardump of a Request object, but none of the data is mine. I have also tried the solution presented by [Access POST values in Symfony2 request object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916324/access-post-values-in-symfony2-request-object) for getting post values without using an object or entity, but I get an error "Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\Form::bindRequest()".

PLEASE HELP.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the [`name`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp) html attribute for your inputs.
If an element of the form misses this attribute, then its data will not be sent.

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls) :

> Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name.

Comment: Ugh, such a stupid oversight. I thought I had them, but I only had the id's. I've been struggling with this for hours! Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome ! You should also have a look to [Symfony forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) to generate this code.