# How to get entity at the controller in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, entities

I have a Product entity and want display a list of products (from database) on page and after that get selected entity in controller.

ProductsType:

```
class ProductsType extends AbstractType
{

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {

    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('products', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'MyBundle:Product',
                'property' => 'description',
                'label' => false,
                'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.description', 'DESC');
                },
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'products';
    }
}
```

Twig template:

```
<form action="{{ path('mgmt_product_update', { 'id': product.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    <strong>Product:</strong>{{ form_widget(form.products) }}
    <button value="update" name="update">Update</button>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
...
public function productUpdateAction() // ?
...
```

How i can get selected product in productUpdateAction() ?
Maybe I'm doing it all wrong and this is not the best solution?

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear if you already [built your form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#building-the-form). So here is the code to display the selected product:

```php
public function productUpdateAction($id)
{
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')
        ->find($product_id);

    $form = $this->createForm(new ProductsType(),
        $product)
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        # get and display the selected product
        return new Response($form->get('products')->getData()->getId());

        # get back to the page once the form was submitted
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('mgmt_product_update',
            array('id' => $id));
    }

    return $this->render('YOUR_TWIG_TEMPLATE', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));    
}
```

Depending on what your goal is (updating the product?), the code should be changed.

Edit: as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916324/access-post-values-in-symfony2-request-object/12142437#12142437), `getData()` will return the object, so you can use `$form->get('products')->getData()->getId()` to access the product ID.