# What is the difference between $this->getRequest() and passing Request as a parameter in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, request

In a controller action we can get the request object in 2 ways:

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
```

or by passing it as a parameter to an action

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
```

What is the difference between them? Is a recommended way to get the request or specific situations when each is preferred?

Comment: the difference is that `testAction()` cannot be called without request on second way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916324/access-post-values-in-symfony2-request-object This thread might help you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is no visible difference before Symfony 2.4. But according to the documentation (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md) you should pass request object as an action method argument.

> The getRequest method of the base Controller class has been deprecated
>   since Symfony 2.4 and must be therefore removed in 3.0. The only
>   reliable way to get the Request object is to inject it in the action
>   method.