# Symfony2. Access to submitted values inside Form Class

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

When a form doesn't validate, I need to access the submitted data inside a Form Class in order I can set some options in a custom field.

I have tried with

```
$data = $builder->getForm()->getData();
$data = $builder->getData();
```

but `$data` has the empty object. So... what is the correct form to access the submitted data by the user after validation error in the form class?

Thanks

Comment: You could try get single field data by: `$fieldData = $builder->getForm()->get('field')->getData();`. But it's rather bad way. What about form events? It would be better solution : ) http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: You could get just the request data: `$this->get('request')->request->get()`. See [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6917440/1847340) for more details.

Comment: I have tried Form Events but I can't find the way to achieve this. I need to add the field in the original form and, if the form does not validate, populate one field with a depending value from other field

Comment: Can you post some more details about your attempt with events? Because I was about to reply with an answer linking to the same page that NHG provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to access submitted data when it has not be handled yet. Basically, when you are in a builder (`buildForm` for the abstract types), you are building your form structure. It has nothing to do with form submission/binding. This is why you get the initial data when you call `$builder->getData()` because it only know the initial data at this state.

Knowing that the form component allows you to access the submitted data via events. You can attach a listener to your builder and rely on one of the `*_submit` event.  The FormEvent class will given you the submitted data with `$event->getData()`.

See this doc for more information: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Answer (score 0):

Look into *$options* variable (var_dump it)

As I remeber you are looking for

```
$options['data']
```

Comment: There is no 'data' index in $options

Answer (score 0):

## Using Form Events.

For those who wonder how Form Events are used.

Here is an example where you can modify the form after the user has tapped the submit button.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
// ...

/* Listener to order to set a price if it does not exist yet */
$builder->get('price')->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();

    // modify it as you wish

    $event->setData($data);
});
```

> The FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT event is dispatched at the beginning of the
>   Form::submit() method.

---

If needed, here is an example where you can modify the form `price` before you display it.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
// ...

/* Listener to order to set a price if it does not exist yet */
$builder->get('price')->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();

    if (null === $data) { $data = '0.00'; }

    $event->setData($data);
});
```

> The FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA event is dispatched at the beginning of
>   the Form::setData() method.