# Get selected option and all request data in twig form

Tags: symfony, twig, forms

I have this form in twig, and I want to get the selected option and the value of the input field from a simple html form:

(PS: Don't say 'You'd better generate a form using the controller!' I know that, but I have a reason why I want to create a form in twig: because that allows me to create as many forms as I want using a for loop.)

I tried to pass arguments in the action path, but that didn't work.

```html
<form action="{{ path('changeProf') }}" method="post" id="form">
    <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9" style="position: relative; left: 35%;top: 6vmin">
        <label style="display:inline-table;">
            <span> <input type="text" value="{{ user.id }}" disabled="true" id="iduser"style="max-width: 18vmin;"/></span>
        </label>
    </section>
    <section class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9"style="position: relative; left: 35%;top: 6vmin">
        <label style="display:inline-table;">
            <span>{% set k=1 %}
                <select id="profil">
                {% for prof in profArr %}
                    <option value="{{ prof }}"> {{ prof }} </option>
                {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </span>
        </label>
    </section>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" style="position: relative;top:18vmin;left:-28%">
</form>
```

This is the action that handles the form :

```php
/**
 * @Route("/profile/chProf",name="changeProf")
 * Method ("POST")
 * @Template()
 */
public function changeProfAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();
    $search = $session->get('user');
    $gestAcces = $session->get('acces');
    $gestEtat = $session->get('etatUser');
    $gestCont = $session->get('contenu');
    $repMsg = $session->get('repMsg');
    $gestRec = $session->get('Reclam');
    $gestMess = $session->get('gestMess');
    $gestMp = $session->get('gestMp');


    if ($search == Null) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('empty', array('search' => $search,
            'contenu' => $gestCont,
            'gestAcces' => $gestAcces,
            'gestEtat' => $gestEtat,
            'repMsg' => $repMsg,
            'gestRec' => $gestRec,
            'gestMess' => $gestMess,
            'gestMp' => $gestMp,
        ));
    }

    $em = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager();
    $reposit = $em->getRepository("CNAMCMSBundle:userprof");
    $rep = $em->getRepository("CNAMCMSBundle:profil");

    $userprof=new userprof();
    $libprof=$request->request->get('profil');
    $iduser=$request->request->get('iduser');

    $idprof=$rep->findOneBy(array('libelle'=>$libprof));
    $userprof->setIdUser($iduser);
    $userprof->setIdProfil($idprof);
    $em->persist($userprof);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('CNAMCMSBundle:Default:userProf.html.twig', array(
        'search'=>$search,
        'contenu'=>$gestCont,
        'gestAcces'=>$gestAcces,
        'gestEtat'=>$gestEtat,
        'repMsg'=>$repMsg,
        'gestRec'=>$gestRec,
        'gestMess'=>$gestMess,
        'gestMp'=>$gestMp,

    ));

}
```

Comment: That's so rude!!! instead of helping poeple stack in problems, they come just to vote (-1) and go!!!!!!!

Comment: what do you mean with "get the info"? Everything posted is within the super global `$_POST`

Comment: First. No one is obliged to help you. Secondly: a probable reason for downvote is the awfully formatted code (indentation) and question body (I tried to break this in parts to be more readable). I didn't downvote but I think as it currently stands your question is fine.

Comment: Please post corresponding controller code.

Comment: @Al.G. I know no one is obliged to help me, but instead of just downvoting, they'd better to help and let me know what's wrong in my code.

Comment: @ASOlivieri I posted the action code, but i think I should change/add something to twig to pass the fields content to the action.

Comment: @DarkBee if it were a form generated by the controller action, I could retrieve its data easily from the request, or by $form->getData(); But for this form I couldn't use those methods.

Comment: @Susan On this line: `$libprof=$request->request->get('profil');` you already get get selected option, right? What is your question?

Comment: this line return 'NULL' and also the other line : $iduser=$request->request->get('iduser');

Comment: whenever i submit the form I get this error : An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO userprof (id_user, id_profil) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id_user' cannot be null

Answer (score 1):

I think I found out what caused the error you receive.

1. `$request->request->get('profil');` returns NULL.
2. This means, the form did *not* send a `profil` entry.
3. Look where is the `profil` in the form:

   ```
   <input type="text" value="{{ user.id }}" disabled="true" id="iduser"style="max-width: 18vmin;"/>
   ```
4. There is no `name` attribute! Which is actually what is sent with the request. The *name* attribute, not the *id*. The *id* is used only for local styles and javascripts.
5. The solution:

   ```
   <input type="text" value="{{ user.id }}" disabled="true" id="iduser" name="iduser" style="max-width: 18vmin;"/>
   ```
6. Do the same for `profil`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but that didn't help, I've tried it before, and retried it now, but I got the same error :(

Comment: @Susan Then I suspect this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12142437/3132718 I.e. create a temporary form and bind it to the request. Then you can use it as if you had a normal form class.

Comment: @AI.G. Thank you soooooooo much i think this will help me. I'll try and post the result

Comment: No, it doesn't work! Do you think it's because I have dynamically genereted forms inside a for loop ???

Comment: The way you generated the form doesn't matter if the data is sent properly. Try a rough `var_dump($_POST);` (in the controller where you receive the form) and see if the fields are sent correctly. If that's the case, you'd have to look at the controller. Otherwise, the twig generation of the form should be inspected.

Comment: It returns only the value of 'profil' but the other input field is not returned array(1) { ["profil"]=> string(7) "medecin" }

Comment: I just saw your `input` was `disabled`, you probably meant `readonly`.

Comment: OOOh hhh  I didn't pay attention to that! But now when I retrieve the value using $request->request(''); I only get the value of the first input which is readable only, but the 'profil' value is {}

Comment: First look at `var_dump($_POST);` and only then at `$request`. See in `$_POST` what values have been sent.

Comment: I couldn't get the return of the var_dump; I got this error :An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO userprof (id_user, id_profil) VALUES (?, ?)' with params ["222", {}]:

Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class CNAM\CMSBundle\Entity\profil could not be converted to string

Comment: Put var_dump right in the beginning of the controller, before the sql query.

Comment: I fixed it by adding  public function __toString() {
        return $this->libelle;
    } to my entity 'profil'